# How can I get Visual Studio to run using the environment I've selected?

Tags: python, visual-studio, environment

First of all, I am extremely new to Python and not formally trained in computer science, so I apologize if some of my terminology is incorrect or missing.

As background information, there are 3 main environments I have been testing, IronPython 2.7 (no numpy), Python 2.7 (numpy installed), and Python 3.7 (no numpy installed).

Regardless of the environment I choose from the drop-down list, Visual Studio will seemingly only run using the Python 3.7 environment. I've tested with simple lines such as "import numpy" and "print 'Hello world'", and regardless of the environments I've chosen and the packages installed for each, I always get errors which indicate it's using the Python 3.7 environment (numpy package not installed, print statement requires parentheses around the argument).

However, when I use the interactive window, it respects the selected environment for the interactive window, and produces the expected results. This even transfers when selecting the environment of the folder containing my script, which matches the environment I've chosen in the main window. It is only when using the "Start project" option that it seems to force into using Python 3.7.

For further information, my original script had been completely functional, and was written to interface with another software, but then there was a deep, multi-week update to the software (and potentially other things, I was only informed about the status of the software) and ever since then it has been non-functional due to this forced use of Python 3.7.

Can anyone tell me why Visual Studio is doing this? How can I get Visual Studio to respect the chosen environment?

EDIT: I have found that by changing the "default" environment for new projects in the Python environments tab, I can change how Visual Studio runs my script. How can I explicitly tell Visual Studio to use Python 2.7 for my script, and not just whatever is set as the "default"?

Comment: Have you checked out the docs? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments seems pretty straightforward. Let me know if this works

Comment: I'm not using Visual Studio Code, I'm using Visual Studio, none of the GUI shown in the documents you linked matches anything that I'm working with.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I misread as VS Code. Check this out for Visual Studio - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/managing-python-environments-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019

Comment: Yes this is what I am using. I've been to this page before, and all the environments I need to use are already installed and listed as options. I can see the file path and the installed packages for each environment. I don't need to add any more, or make a virtual environment. My problem is that Visual Studio is ignoring the environment I have selected. No matter what environment I choose, it runs it through what I am assuming is Python 3.7.